# Geting error during bootup

Tags: debian, boot, acpi

Hello I am getting following error during boot-up (debian12) on black screen:

```
[    0.079398] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.213198] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[    0.213208] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.CR01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[    0.249586] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[    0.249594] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

what are these error? do I need to worry?

Comment: some one pointed me to https://web.archive.org/web/20171228022907/https://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24

Answer (score 1):

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
```

It's a notification that [Intel Software Guard Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions) have been disabled by BIOS. That feature could be used for various things, including Digital Rights Management and protection of encryption keys against other programs running in the system. There have also been some security vulnerabilities related to SGX as implemented in certain processor models, and some have suspected there could be more of them still undiscovered, so if you don't need the SGX features, having them disabled might be a good thing: one less potential attack vector to worry about.

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.CR01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
```

According to [ACPI specifications](https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/06_Device_Configuration/Device_Configuration.html), the _PLD object describes the physical location of some device. Assuming these two messages are related to each other, they might be referring to the physical location of USB Type-C connector(s).

- `\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB` could be a device path: system bus -> PCI bus 0 -> XHCI USB controller -> USB root hub (-> `TPLD` = `T`ype-C `P`hysical `L`ocation `D`ata perhaps?)
- `\_SB.UBTC.CR01._PLD` could be the method to retrieve the physical location of the USB Type-C (`UBTC`) port referred by identifier `CR01` ("connector 01"?).

On typical desktop motherboards that are sold separately, this kind of physical location information is often left unpopulated in the firmware, as the motherboard manufacturer cannot know what kind of chassis the user will be placing the motherboard into, and so the physical location of the connector will be unknown. The motherboard vendor just hasn't disabled this location information "cleanly": there was at least one reference to the missing information left in the ACPI code.

Unless you are an ACPI programming expert, you cannot easily fix this. However, it's unlikely to ever cause you any practical problems, so you can safely ignore this message. (It's basically meant to be a reminder for BIOS/UEFI coders to do a better job next time.)

```
platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

`MSFT0101` is a Plug'n-Play identifier for the TPM chip. Maybe your system has a socket for a TPM chip, but no TPM chip installed? Or maybe some other hardware installed into your system is blocking the first memory address the system tried to assign for the TPM, and the system needed to select an alternate configuration for it? (In the latter case, there would be a lower-priority kernel log messages somewhere in the boot log about a second, successful attempt to assign a different memory address range for the TPM.)

If you don't need to use a TPM chip for anything, or your TPM chip actually works, you can ignore these messages.